# How to open an edit form using post request between postback using laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have searched a lot but did not got any clue. So i am putting my question here.

I have created user account where user or admin can update or edit the user info. For the security reason we can not use get request to open edit form instead we have to use post method whenever particular user profile link is clicked.

I am able to open the the edit form based on post request and i am also able to check the request whether request arrive using get method or post and their parameters.

Now actual problem start here, where i submit the from which was open for edit and contains any validation error it does not redirect using post method, it create problem. It give me "MethodNotAllowedHttpException". I know it is because, it redirect back using get request. But i want it should be via post request.

If anybody requires code support i can try to give, but i am not sure i can.

Thanks.

Comment: What are those security reason that prevent you from showing form on GET request? I can't think of any.

Comment: Like http://example.com/user/1/edit. If i remove 1 and replace it with 2 or any number than it may breach the normal flow. I know that i can hash it but that can also hacked.

Comment: POST method is not any safer, there are still ways to change the URL request is going to. And I don't think it's worth worrying about users messing with the URLs and getting unexpected results - I'd just make sure the error page is nice and informative and that access to other users data is protected on the backend side.

Comment: I can understand your point, but the issue is that my company want that every request should be proceed using post method except for those pages which does not require any input. Actually earlier my company was using core php and they are doing the same thing over there. But now they want to switch to particular framework like laravel.

Comment: Anyway, you won't be able to redirect to a page using a method other than GET.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. Let me see what i can do further.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do a redirect to any method other than **GET**. Location header that is used to do the redirect just tells the browser "where to go" and browser just goes there using the **GET** HTTP method.